# Google Sheets Conditional formatting across sheets with 2 criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to highlight the whole row in the sheet 'To colour' if the email address appears in the 'Original' sheet (which I have managed see Conditional Formatting custom formula) AND if the value in the column E on 'Original' sheet is blank.

On my 'To colour' sheet, it should only be Paul Hall and David Wilson's rows that are highlighted.

Thank you

[Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xLUEEy8OEck9lR5iCHG_BhAnOVNjl2G6-1A3KbbueUc/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=isblank(vlookup($A2,indirect("Original!B:E"),4,))
```

[image]